# Common Point of Intersection of n-dimensional ellipsoids

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Suppose we have two ellipses in 2-dimensions centered at the origin. It is easy to visualize that (unless one is contained in the other) they will have 4 points of intersection. Can we say that in three dimensions, three generic ellipsoids will have a common point of intersection (unless one is contained in the other) or is there a counterexample?  Is there a similar result in n-dimensions?